# Translate CSS IDs to all attributes

Tags: css, web

I am wondering if there is a simple way to look at a page which uses CSS IDs/Classes and be presented with all of the styles used in the ids/classes on each html element?

For instance:

If you saw  is there a way - apart from manually going through each attached css document - to see `<div style="width:###px; width:###py; align:center">`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser inspect element feature can help you achieve that

**Firefox** browser

1. Right-click the page in question
2. From the list of items, choose inspect element
3. From the new window that opens at the bottom area of the screen,
   click on the pointer icon at the very left
4. Now hover over the element that you'd like to
   inspect.
5. As you hover over the individual elements, you'll see the block of
   CSS that controls it on the right hand side of the inspection window
   that's at the bottom. you can copy it, or edit and see instant changes

[Firefox page inspector tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)

[Video tutorial on how to inspect element in firefox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7fUtZh6APw)

Comment: Is there any way to do this for a group of elements? This for instance:

<div class="row-fluid">
    <!--Video-->
    <div class="span9">
       <div class="flex-video widescreen">

Comment: @Abraxas - Oops! I thought you wanted to loop through the stylesheet and display all rules on the page.

Comment: My suggestion is the browser element inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used "Inspect Element"?
It gives you a overview of the element, with only the relevant lines in the CSS files.
(you can find "Inspect Element" in the right menu window of a decent browser.